# QUnit - comparing hidden inputs - TypeError: selectionDirection on input

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I want to compare two blocks of elements and see that they are the same. The items that I want to compare has hidden inputs, and I'm hitting this error, which I think has to do with the hidden inputs:

TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.

Here's a simplified version of my code (and also what's in JSFiddle):

```
test("compare input", function() {
  var input1 = $('<input/>').attr("value", 'cool_play');
  var input2 = $('<input/>').attr("value", 'cool_play');
  deepEqual(input1, input2);
});

test("compare hidden input", function() {
  var input1 = $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("value", 'cool_play');
  var input2 = $('<input/>').attr("type", "hidden").attr("value", 'cool_play');
  deepEqual(input1, input2);
});​
```

First example passes, but the second example throws an error.

Here's jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/HLG5y/1/

Is there a way to compare input elements with hidden class? Am I trying this in a wrong way? Thank you. I feel like I should be able to compare hidden inputs, too.

Comment: It seems like `deepEqual` compares each property of the objects, and doing so throws an error for that specific DOM property on hidden inputs. Maybe you could define more precisely when two inputs are equal (e.g. manually check only type and class).

Comment: @pimvdb - I would, but what I'm comparing is actually a block of nested elements, and input element is all the way in the center of it. If there's no way around it, I guess I will have to compare pieces of it one by one. :(

Comment: What I mean is that it's error-prone - for example, if you add the elements of case #1 to the DOM to the same parent, their `nextSibling` becomes different and they suddenly would not be equal anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution, but I got around this by comparing

```
equal(actual.html(), expected.html());
```

where actual and expected are blocks of elements.